# Invoke Web Services via Drupal?

Tags: drupal, soap, web, service

Within a Drupal subsite, http://subsite.site.com, I'm putting together a form, whose data will come in as a webservice.

Basically, how do I build that out?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Web Service Client module](https://www.drupal.org/project/wsclient).
Or use the function [drupal_http_request](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7)